# How to move back to the starting of previous line after reading a line using fgets()?

Tags: c, file, io

For example if the file contains:

```
12345
-3445654
1245646
```

I want to read the first line into a string using `fgets()`. Then I want to read the second line in too check if there is a `'-'` in the first spot. If there is one, I will read the second line and `strcat` it to the first line.

Then I want to read the thrid line using `fgets()` again. This time when there is no `'-'` I just want to make the file go back to the beginning of the third line so that the next time I call `fgets()` it will read the same third line again.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: The IO mechanism of C is called "stream" IO intentionally.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the input looks like the following (the `'/'` characters represent newlines): `12345/-3445654/-1245646`?  Or what if the first line that you read starts with `'-'`?

Comment: And do you want to be able to do this on a stream that cannot perform a `seek()` operation?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You say "I want to read the third line again". But the first paragraph never said it read the third line, it just read the first and second lines.

Comment: If you really want to go back, use `ftell()` before reading the line, than use `fseek()` to go back to where you were when you called `ftell()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fgetc to read the first character on the next line, and if it's not a '-' use ungetc to put it back.

Comment: If instead of "-", i look for a tab "\t" at the start of the string. Will a single ungetc also put it back at the same position it was before? Or will I have to ungetc many times since a tab takes many spaces.

Comment: A tab character is only a single character.

Comment: @Brandon: Read the manpages of the functions! `ungetch` is not guaranteed to unget more than a single character.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would just keep the part of the file just read, in the memory until you are sure you don't need it anymore.

Or you could read the entire file into a buffer and then jump around it using pointer as much as you like.

Or if you really must, you can more the current stream position with [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/), and then re-read the parts you need.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I want to

1. read a line
2. read a second line
3. maybe do something involving both the first line and the second line

what I usually do is declare a second line-holding variable

```
char prevline[whateversize];
```

and then, somewhere between step 1 and step 2

```
strcpy(prevline, line);
```

(Naturally you have to be sure that the `line` and `prevline` variables are consistently allocated, e.g. as arrays of the same size, so that overflow isn't a problem.)